# __init__が呼び出されずAttributeErrorと表示される。

Tags: python

初歩的なミスなのかもしれませんが、どなたか教えてください・・・

以下のコード↓

```
class Set:
    def __init__(self, value = []):
        self.data = []
        self.concat(value)

    def intersect(self, other):
        res = []
        for x in self.data:
            if x in other:
                res.append(x)
        return Set(res)

def union(self, other):
    res = self.data[:]
    for x in other:
        if not x in res:
            res.append(x)
    return Set(res)

def concat(self, value):
    for x in value:
        if not x in self.data:
            self.data.append(x)

def __len__(self):          return len(self.data)
def __getitem__(self, key): return self.data[key]
def __and__(self, other):   return self.intersect(other)
def __or__(self, other):    return self.union(other)
def __repr__(self):         return 'Set:' + `self.data`
```

を書いたうえで、次に↓

```
>>> x = Set([1,2,3,4])
```

と実行しますと↓

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    x = Set([1,2,3,4])
  File "", line 4, in **init**
    self.concat(value)
AttributeError: Set instance has no attribute 'concat'
と表示されます。
concatを属性として持っていないというエラーだと思うのですが、この場合の対処法または、コードの不備等があれば教えて頂きたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: concatの関数ありますか selfはクラスのスコープからです。

Comment: すいません、こちらがコード全体になります。
不備等あれば教えてください・・・
お願い致します。

Comment: concatはクラスの外からで動かないです

Comment: 本当だ・・・、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

pythonはインデントによってブロックを認識します。

そのため、`def concat`等がSetのメソッドだと仮定すると、`class Set:`よりも1つ階層が下のインデントで書かなければ動作しません。

ついでに、`if x not in res`が正しい記法です。

```py
class Set:
    def __init__(self, value=[]):
        self.data = []
        self.concat(value)

    def intersect(self, other):
        res = []
        for x in self.data:
            if x in other:
                res.append(x)
        return Set(res)

    def union(self, other):
        res = self.data[:]
        for x in other:
            if x not in res:
                res.append(x)
        return Set(res)

    def concat(self, value):
        for x in value:
            if x not in self.data:
                self.data.append(x)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __and__(self, other):
        return self.intersect(other)

    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.union(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Set:' + str(self.data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Set([1, 2, 3, 4])
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

concatはクラスの外に存在しますので動かないです。selfが必要ないです。

```
concat(self, value)
```

Comment: 本当に初歩的なミスでした・・・
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 大丈夫です、
直すができた良かったです。

Comment: この文脈の場合、「クラス内部にconcatメソッドを書け、インデントルールを確認しろ」が適切な回答では？